# Python random pick from list without previous pick

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list and I randomly print one of its items, but I want to print another random item from the list and I want to be 100% sure it's not the previous one.

```
import random
i = 0
Names = ["Andrew", 'John', 'Jacob','Bob']

for l in Names:
    i += 1


c = random.randrange(0,i)
print(Names[c])
```

Comment: [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample)

Answer (score 5):

Use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to select unique elements from a given sequence, like this

```
import random

Names = ['Andrew', 'John', 'Jacob', 'Bob']

choice = random.sample(Names, 2) # choose 2 unique names from Names

print(choice[0])
print(choice[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
random.shuffle(names)
names[0] # first pick
names[1] # second pick ... also guaranteed not to be first pick
```

another alternative is to remove the names from the list as you randomly pick them

```
names =[...]
random1 = names.pop(random.randint(0,len(names)))
random2 = names.pop(random.randint(0,len(names)))
```

Comment: `names.pop()` is what he wanted I believe.

Comment: why ? it would work certainly but what makes it a better choice?

Comment: I meant `random.shuffle(names)` and `names.pop()` instead of accessing by index. No need to keep the names after use.